# valet install produces error in Nginx.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

I'm trying to set up laravel and valet. When running valet install I am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Valet\Site::aliasLoopback(): Argument #2 ($loopback) must be of type string, null given, called in /Users/bonds/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/Valet/Nginx.php on line 108 and defined in /Users/bonds/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/cli/Valet/Site.php:831
```

I'm on the latest version of PHP (8.2.4) and running valet version 4.0.0

I have not been able to find many issues on the web similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `"loopback": "127.0.0.1",` to the `~/.config/valet/config.json` file worked for me.

I had to follow the code for this one and assume it's a bug. Hope this helps!